# Font rendering issue

Tags: fonts

I have an issue about font quality. Recently I changed my desktop monitor. After that, I have a font quality issue. As I attached picture, you can see the font is a little blurry. But when I use this monitor with the MS windows desktop, there is no any font quality issue. It looks perfect.

As I figured the issue, it looks about sub-pixel channel issue. But even I tried to changed some options (hinting, anti-aliasing, sub-pixel chanel order)
It didn't work for me.

Can it be monitor driver problem or am I miss something font setting? Can anyone give me feedback for this?

[image]

Comment: Is font smoothing enabled?

Comment: What model of monitor are you using now?

Comment: Is Ubuntu using the native resolution of the monitor?